# A particular subgroup of the general linear group

Tags: group-theory, matrices

Say a $n \times n$ matrix with real coefficients $a_{ij}$ has property P if $\sum_j a_{ij} >0, \forall i$. Say a group (or subgroup) of matrices has property P if every element has property P.

What would be the biggest subgroup of the general linear group $\text{GL}_ n(\mathbb{R})$ having property P ?

I'm alread having some problems for the $2 \times 2$ case. I found that matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & b\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & a \\
b & 0\end{bmatrix}$ with strictly positive coefficients work, obviously, as well as matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
0 & 1+a\end{bmatrix}$ ($a > 0$), but I don't see a general way of doing it.

Comment: What you describe is not a subgroup.

Comment: Also, given that you had a sum in the definition, your last example of such a matrix would only require $a>-1$.

Comment: @Tobias I don't think that OP is asking whether the set of all $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $\sum_j a_{ij}>0$ is a subgroup.  I think he is asking for a characterization of subgroups for which that property holds.

Comment: I can see how confusing this can be, I will try to reformulate...

Comment: Do we know a characterization of those matrices $A$ such that the cyclic group generated by $A$ has property $P$? I think that would be a useful starting point. An interesting question actually.

Comment: In dimension 1, the subgroup in question is simply the multiplicative group of strictly positive reals, which is the image of the additive group of reals by an exponential homomorphism. Here, matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
0 & 1+a\end{bmatrix}$ are exponentials of matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b \\
0 & b\end{bmatrix}$, and diagonal or antidiagonal matrices can also be expressed as exponentials. So I'm thinking, maybe there is a relation between matrices having property P and matrix exponentials ?

Answer (score 4):

Do I get it right, you want the sum of the elements in each row to be positive. So you are considering linear maps which take the vector $[1,1, \dots, 1]^{t}$ to a vector with positive entries.

My idea about constructing a biggish subgroup of maps like that would be to take a basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$ of the underlying vector space $V$ which has $e_1 = [1,1, \dots, 1]^{t}$ as its first element. Then define a subgroup $G$ of $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ by
$$
G = \left\{ g \in GL(V) : \text{$g(e_1) = a e_{1}$,  for some $a > 0$} \right\}.
$$

In the case $n = 2$ you get $[1,1]^{t} \mapsto [a,a]^{t}$, and say $[0,1]^{t} \mapsto [b,c]^{t}$, with $a > 0$ and $b \ne c$ not both zero. Then with respect to the standard basis you get the group of matrices
$$
G = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a-b&b\\a-c&c\end{bmatrix}
:
\text{$a > 0$, $b \ne c$,  $b$ and $c$ not both zero} \right\}.
$$

However, your first two examples do not fit in. I believe this might mean there is no unique maximal subgroup with respect this property. Although this is no conclusive evidence, note, for instance, that the matrices
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-1&2\\-2&3\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}-1&3\\-2&3\end{bmatrix}
$$
satisfy the condition, while their product
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-3&3\\-4&3\end{bmatrix}
$$
does not.